# How can I copy picture and text from one file into another file dynamically using node.js

Tags: node.js

Suppose i have two files a_b_c_d.txt and e_f_g_h.png S,At runtime i.e., by using command prompt i have to create b folder inside that c folder inside that d folder inside that a.txt and same also for another file f->g->h->e.png and i have some text in a and image in epng . .So,how can I get values from those existing file into created files. .

Comment: i dont think node.js is the best tool to do this. If you have an option to use something like python or bash, that would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the file system operations inside the fs module. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

But like tapan says if you need to do complex synchronous execution that manipulates the file system something like Bash will be a lot better suited for that.

Comment: I have to do in node.js only. .SO any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you correctly you want to take a file named "a_b_c_d.txt" in some folder, and move that into a nested folder as:

```
    ./a_b_c_d.txt -> ./b/c/d/a.txt
```

The general solution would be:

1. Grab the file name using [`process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) if it varies.
   For example, if you supply the file as an argument to node, e.g. 
   `node move.js "a_b_c_d.txt"`, the argument, "a_b_c_d.txt", will be in the argv array.
2. Process the file name using a combination of [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods) and [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2).

   - Nodes current directory is stored in the [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) global variable
     if you need it.
   - You can split the extension from the rest of the path 
     using string's [`split(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. 
     For the above argument, `split('.')` will result in the array `['a_b_c_d', 'txt']`
   - You can then split `'a_b_c_d'` using `'_'`, 
     and use various array operations to pull the file name `'a'` 
     out of the array, so that you're left with the path `['b', 'c', 'd']` 
     and the file name and extension sitting in their own variables somewhere.
3. Use [`fs.mkdirSync(...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode) on the path array to make each nested folder, 
   starting with `b` (e.g. using array's [`forEach(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method).
   You could also use the async `fs.mkdir(...)` and supply callbacks, 
   but the sync version is easier in this case.
4. Finally use [`fs.renameSync(...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_path1_path2) to move `./a_b_c_d.txt` to `./b/c/d/a.txt`.

As you can see, python or bash (as tapan suggested) would probably be simpler for this use case, but if for some reason you *have* to use node, the above advice will hopefully be enough to get you started.

Comment: There were more links, but being "new" I can't post them. Leaving it as is.

Comment: k. .so to me inplace of b,i want as balaji folder. .and that name i have to  come from textfile b.txt . .In textfile i written as b,balaji And reading from console. .and in ANother function i have for loop like that function GetCategoryNameFromLookup(categoryName) {
    for (var loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < b.length; loopIndex++) {
        if (categoryName === b[loopIndex].key) {
            return b[loopIndex].value;
        }
    }
    return "";
} BUt IAm not geeting,Can anyone tel me?

Comment: in console im written as node prepare.js "source" "destination" "path of b.txt"

Comment: Balaji, I added the links that were left out back in. Check them out, and if you still need help, update your question with specifics. Code's very difficult to read in your comment. Thanks! :)

Comment: ya..I followed ur steps as u mentioned above. .It works fine as i did same . .but i have to read from text file. .so how can?

Comment: You can use [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_encoding) for that. For plain-text files, make sure your set an `encoding` option.

Comment: var category = path.normalize(process.argv[4]); In above way i read file from console and i want to use category variable inplace of category.txt in below line
    var categoryArray = fs.readFile('category.txt').toString().split("\n");
How can i do it? Directly i read category.txt file. .